# date format in d3, would like to have month as an integer instead of decimal

Tags: d3.js, datetime-format

I would like to have format as 6/19 instead of 06/19 for my X axis. It does not seem to provide a way of doing so on its official documentation:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Any clues? Thanks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the part about padding:

> The % sign indicating a directive may be immediately followed by a padding modifier:
>
> - `0` - zero-padding
> - `_` - space-padding
> - `-` - disable padding

For example, `"%-m/%-d"` will disable padding for both the month and date, giving you "6/1" for June 1st, as opposed to `"%m/%d"` which gives "06/01".

Comment: yes thanks! I also noticed that this works with d3 v3 but not d3 v2.

Comment: Time to upgrade! See the [release notes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Release-Notes).