# d3.time.format disabled zero padding not matching (d3 v3.5.16)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using the wiki for time formatting here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

However I can't seem to be able to get my format to match

%-m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%s %p

4/25/2014 4:09:14 PM

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%-m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%s %p");
     psmsData.forEach(function(d) {
     document.write(d["Date"] + " ")
     d["Date"] = dateFormat.parse(d["Date"])
     document.write(d["Date"] + "<br>");
});
```

Output:

```
4/25/2014 4:09:14 PM null
4/26/2014 6:10:47 PM null
5/3/2014 11:15:29 PM null
5/3/2014 11:34:34 PM null
5/7/2014 4:29:18 PM null
5/7/2014 5:12:57 PM null
6/21/2014 6:00:04 PM null
7/28/2014 6:00:03 AM null
```

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/q/16681038/2015890 it also looks like the disabled padding format should work

Answer (score 0):

`%-m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p` not `%-m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%s %p`

Thought I was going crazy.